# Hive : Expand a single record into multiple records when column values are separated by delimiter (~)

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have the following information

```
id     user                 date                          test

102   123~456~897   01JAN2019~6JUL2018~21DEC2017        abc~qwer~~wer~
103  13~45~88~34   01JAN2020~6JUN2019~21JAN2018~12MAR2017 pqr~~qw~wer*123~qwerty
```

The result I need, the records must be expanded based on ascending date.

```
id      user     date            test 

102     897      21DEC2017        wer
102     456      06JUL2018        qwer
102     123      01JAN2019        abc
103     34       12MAR2017        qwerty
103     88       21JAN2018        wer*123
103     45       06JUN2019        qw
103     13       01JAN2020        pqr
```

I tried with lateral View posexplode, but it's not working  properly, please help.

```
a.id, 
    from demo a
    lateral view posexplode(a.test,'\\~')) t1 as exploded_test,test
    lateral view posexplode(a.user,'\\~')) t2 as exploded_user, user
    lateral view posexplode(a.date,'\\~')) t3 as exploded_date, date
    where exploded_test == exploded_user and exploded_user == exploded_date
    order by 1,3
```

Comment: Can you format your data to understand problem? what I understood is you've 3 input rows , if possible can you break down your input rows to columns based on your delimiter and then format your desired output ?

Comment: Did my best to  format, can some one give me tips on how to format properly, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tilde (`~`) is not a metacharacter in Java regex (Hive uses Java regex) and does not need escaping. Also [posexplode](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-posexplode(array)) or explode can be applied to array, you need to split string to get an array before exploding. Use `posexplode(split(a.user,'~+')) t1 as (pos,user)`

Also (this is just an opinion): I would not name the array position as "exploded_test". `pos` or `position` or simply `p` would look less confusing

Comment: thanks , but in my question above , there are multiple ~ separating the values, I want to ignore multiple occurances of  ~ and only consider single occurance of ~. Is it possible to achieve that with posexplode

Comment: @shanmukh According to the desired result in the question, I believe you are trying to consider multiple tildes as the single one and split by it, right? Then use `'~+'` in the regexp, it means: one or more tilde. Edited the answer